# Monodevelop 5.9 (GNU Debugger?)

Tags: c++, c, debugging, monodevelop, gnu

I recently installed Monodevelop 5.9 under Linux Lite 2.6 (Ubuntu 14.04 variant), and can't seem to find the proper monodevelop-debugger-gbd package to install for C/C++ debugging.

The only one Synaptic is showing me is for version Monodevelop 4.0, and I can't seem to locate any information on the proper PPA to use for a compatible 5.9 debugger (Synaptic won't let me install the older debugger).

I really don't want to roll back to Monodevelop 4.0, and currently, I can't debug any C/C++ code, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: an older debugger version (for the correct architecture) should work just fine with the newer compiler version.   However, you can download the source code for the gdb debugger, then configure/compile/install it your self

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was confused between the actual GNU Debugger, and the MonoDevelop Plugin for the GNU Debugger. Turns out I never had the debugger installed, which is why the plugin was yelling at me. Thanks for the insight, it help point me in the write direction.